# Enigma between Colleagues (Part2)

Tags: number-sequence

Let's give a second try with something more creative.

Here is the sequence :

> 161 = B
>
> 198 = W
>
> 173 = ∅
>
> 246 = B
>
> 215 = W
>
> 227 = B
>
> 192 = ∅
>
> 184 = ?

Don't hesitate to comment some improvement for our next enigma :)

Hint 1:

> Welcome on board of this not so colorful enigma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 184 = B

Reasoning

> First convert each number to hexadecimal.
>  Notice that some of these hexadecimal numbers correspond to squares on a chessboard in algebraic notation.
>  If such a square is **black**, the number maps to B, if it is **white**, it maps to W and if it is not a chessboard square, it maps to ∅.
>  Explicitly,
>  161 $\rightarrow$ a1 $\rightarrow$ black square $\rightarrow$ B
>  198 $\rightarrow$ c6 $\rightarrow$ white square $\rightarrow$ W
>  173 $\rightarrow$ ad $\rightarrow$ not a square $\rightarrow$ ∅
>  246 $\rightarrow$ f6 $\rightarrow$ black square $\rightarrow$ B
>  215 $\rightarrow$ d7 $\rightarrow$ white square $\rightarrow$ W
>  227 $\rightarrow$ e3 $\rightarrow$ black square $\rightarrow$ B
>  192 $\rightarrow$ c0 $\rightarrow$ not a square $\rightarrow$ ∅
>  184 $\rightarrow$ b8 $\rightarrow$ black square $\rightarrow$ B